# Is getSimCountryIso returning 3 letters or 2 letters ISO code

Tags: android

I was wondering, is [`getSimCountryIso`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso%28%29) returning 2 letters or 3 letters ISO code? As this is not being mentioned in the documentation. I tested with my Nexus phone, it is returning 2 letters. However, I'm not sure this is true for other phones.

Answer (score 6):

It returns whatever the OEM has configured for the gsm.sim.operator.iso-country property, which in my experience is a 2-character code. The codes I have seen match the Alpha-2 code from ISO 3166-1 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). This is based on my observation as I was unable to find this in any official documentation.

Comment: Yes, I think that when they say "ISO country code" they mean 'alpha-2'.  I've seen cases where they return alpha-3 and they are explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

From the SIM cards I tried it returns **lowercase** two letter country codes.